# How does the Google App Engine Logging Levels work?

Tags: google-app-engine

This makes zero sense to me:

**Code**

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("SomeClassName");
l.log(Level.SEVERE, "-------start------");      
l.log(Level.INFO, "INFO Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.WARNING, "WARNING Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.SEVERE, "SEVERE Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.CONFIG, "CONFIG Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.FINEST, "FINEST Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.OFF, "OFF Two... Two...");
System.out.println("CONSOLE Two... Two...");
l.log(Level.SEVERE, "-------end------");
```

**Result**

[image: AppEngine log screenshot]

What's up with "OFF" resulting in "ERROR", and "INFO" not being logged at all? Also, [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Logging) states that Console-output also shall be logged as INFO. Not happening.

Comment: Please show your WEB-INF/logging.properties content. For me it worked to change the log level inside the logging.properties .

Comment: one non-commented line: ".level = WARNING". I think we both know the answer now ;-)

Comment: Yeah :D . Should I write an answer to close the question?